# Java replacing character in string from the back

Tags: java, string, for-loop

I was having some problem when trying to replace certain character with ASCII character in the string.

So let's say I got this string "CCCCCCC". After perform some method, it will become "CCCCCCa". Then the second time I will be checking the second last character and perform some method to get "CCCCCca". Then third time will be checking the third last character and so on and repeat for 7 times.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256; i++){          
        plaintext = plaintext .substring(0,plaintext .length() - counter) + Character.toString((char)i);
}
```

I used a for loop to loop through all 256 ASCII characters. The counter will be incremented after I performed some decryption. So basically for the first time, it will be -1 (which is the last character) then second time will be -2 (which is the second last character) and so on for the substring.

Let me put it this way, for the first time, I want all 256 ASCII appended to the end of my 7 bytes string. Then after I perform some decryption, the string will become CCCCCCCa. So when I loop for the second time, I will replace my second last character in the string with all 256 ASCII. And after some decryption, the string will become CCCCCC(a. Then I loop until there is no more C in the string.

However, I am getting String index out of range: -1 error message. Is there any other way to replace the last character of a string with decreased size by 1 after each for loop?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is value of `counter`?

Comment: First, you forget to add the right part of the String (after the character you changed), so you lose one character each loop (except the first). And of course, if you increment `counter` somewhere in that loop, you will eventually try to `substring(0,-1) ` You need to iterate `plaintext.length()` times, not 256. PS : I would not use `Character` below 20 since those are special code)

Comment: counter was initialized to 1. Then after I perform some decryption at the lower part I will increment it. What I trying to do is replacing the last character of the string which is not in uppercase

Comment: And on the side note, I think you should consider using `StringBuilder` for such purposes. (Or `StringBuffer` if you want Thread safety)

Comment: You are not reading. you are loosing the part after the character you change, so the length is always shorter (leading to your first problem). Then, since you are loop to many time (256 for String that could be any length) you will eventually good to far. @AnandUndavia I would suggest a simple `char[]` personnaly since the length is fixed

Comment: I found this whereby it can replace the char at certain position: public static String replaceCharAt(String s, int pos, char c) {
   return s.substring(0,pos) + c + s.substring(pos+1);
}

Answer (score 0):

First, don't forget the rest.

```
    plaintext = plaintext.substring(0,plaintext .length() - counter) 
                     + Character.toString((char)i)
                     + plaintext.substring(plaintext .length() - counter + 1) ; //TO add the rest
```

Then, you need to check if counter is not larger than `plaintext.length()`

```
for (int i = 0; i < 256 && counter <= plaintext.length(); i++){
```

I would suggest to use `String.toCharArray()` and iterate from the end, this would be much easier.

```
char[] array = plaintext.toCharArray();
for(int i = array.length - 1, char c = 0; i >= 0; --i){
    array[i] = c++;
}
```

Example of both code:  (using 'a' as a first character instead of 0)

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String plaintext = "CCCCCC";
    for (int i = 'a', counter = 1; i < 256 && counter <= plaintext.length(); i++, ++counter) {
        plaintext = plaintext.substring(0, plaintext.length() - counter)
                + Character.toString((char) i)
                + plaintext.substring(plaintext.length() - counter + 1);
    }

    System.out.println(plaintext);
    plaintext = "CCCCCC"; //fedcba
    char[] array = plaintext.toCharArray();
    char c = 'a';
    for (int i = array.length - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
        array[i] = c++;
    }
    System.out.println(new String(array)); //fedcba
}
```

> fedcba
>
> fedcba

Comment: By implementing as suggested by you, the loop for ASCII stops at 65 and then continue to replace the second last and so on.

Comment: @DeniseTan Which one ? I provide to solution here ;) And I didn't test those to be honnest, might have done a typo

Comment: @DeniseTan like I though, the first for loop had a typo, it is `counter <= plaintext.length()`

Comment: I am trying to debug also :( Might have conflicted with other parts of my code. Because so far it is looping 65 times for each of the position starting from the back to front. Then once everything is finish, it throws me IndexOutOfBoundException

Comment: @DeniseTan Can't help if you don't post a [mcve]. I just post mine example